# Change to theme Resource Limit Is Reached error 508

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I recently followed instructions from a topic on the WordPress forums which provided a guide to creating separate theme pages, so that one could allocate categories to specific pages. However, after making the changes, my site became inaccessible. The error returned was:

"Resource Limit Is Reached
The website is temporarily unable to service your request as it exceeded resource limit. Please try again later."

I have actually already reverted the changes, but the site is still down. I contacted the host and all they did was confirm what I already knew - the CPU limit was reached.

I'm a complete noob, and made the fatal mistake of thinking I understood what I was doing, with limited knowledge of coding.

I can't find the exact instructions, but this topic seems to cover the same process that I used:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/list-post-links-from-a-certain-category?replies=9

I can also provide the error report, if that helps.

I know this topic has been covered before, but I'm looking to find out exactly what I need to change to prevent the CPU usage from exceeding the limit, given what I did to cause the problem in the first place. I'm using Hosting24 at the minute.

I will be hugely grateful if anyone can dig me out of this hole I've dug myself so deeply into.

Comment: I managed to fix the issue through some serious Google-fu. Does anyone know of a plugin that will perform the same function? Re: The ability to have specific categories post to a separate page from the home page?